# How select derived props in Aggregate function with 2 class

Tags: c#, .net, linq, properties, derived-class

Plz help with `System.Linq.Aggregate`

I have the following class

```
public class MainClass
{
   public ClassA someProp { get; set; }
   public ClassA someProp2 { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
   public virtual Type Types => Type.None;
}

public class ClassB:ClassA
{
   public override Type Types => Type.Default;
        
   public string FieldName { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC:ClassA
{
   public override Type Types => Type.Value;
        
   public int FieldValue { get; set; }
}
```

And i want to get FieldName if it is filled in ClassB or the value from ClassC if it is also filled for someProp2 and someProp

I understand how to get 1 value

```
//for get name
    IEnumerable<string> values = entities
    .Where(x=>x.someProp!=null || x.someProp2!=null)
    .SelectMany(mainClass => new[] {mainClass.someProp,mainClass.someProp2 })
    .OfType<ClassB>()
    .Select(classB => classB.FieldName)
//for get value
IEnumerable<int> values = entities
    .Where(x=>x.someProp!=null || x.someProp2!=null)
    .SelectMany(mainClass => new[] {mainClass.someProp,mainClass.someProp2 })
    .OfType<ClassC>()
    .Select(classC => classC.FieldValue)
```

but I don’t understand how to get 2 values in 1 requests, because there will be type 2 classes `ClassB and ClassC`

Probably the best way would be through the Aggregate method!

Tell me how to make the conditions for the selection and the Aggregate method itself

Comment: Can you post what you want the input and output lists to look like?

Comment: and what exactly to describe?

I have a class and, depending on the situation, i fill the name or the value for the `someProp` and `someProp2`

then I need to get these names and make a mapping. the problem is to get the field names from these properties ... as I understand it, I need to do some kind of check for the data type (not int !?) and do everything it in the aggregation function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `.Aggregate()` to achieve your goal, I would suggest that you use an [overload that lets you define a seed in addition to the accumulator function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-aggregate-2(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-1-system-func((-1-0-1)))) after flattening the property pairs.

It could be implemented as follows:

```csharp
IEnumerable<string> values = entities
    .SelectMany(ent => new[] { ent.someProp, ent.someProp2 })
    .Aggregate(new List<string>(),
        ( fields, property ) => 
        {
            if (property is ClassB)
            {
                fields.Add(((ClassB)property).FieldName);
            }
            else if (property is ClassC)
            {
                fields.Add(((ClassC)property).FieldValue.ToString());
            }
            
            return fields;
        });
```

Here, our **seed** is

```csharp
new List<string>()
```

and our **accumulator function** is

```csharp
( fields, property ) => 
{
    // accumulation logic
    return fields;
}
```

, containing the **accumulator value** parameter `fields` and element parameter `property`.

Our seed is the initial value of our accumulator value. For the first `property` in the flattened property collection (provided by the `.SelectMany()`), our accumulator value (`fields`) is therefore an empty list of strings.

For each element (`property`), field values are extraced based on the property's class type:

- if `property` is a `ClassB`, `FieldName` is extracted and added to our accumulator value.
- if `property` is a `ClassC`, `FieldValue` is extracted, and its string value is added to our accumulator value.
- (if `property` is neither of those classes, nothing is added to `fields`).

After conditionally adding a field value to `fields`, `fields` is returned from the accumulator function to be used as the accumulator value in the next iteration of the accumulator function (i.e. for the next `property` in the flattened collection).

---

For `entities` given as follows:

```csharp
List<MainClass> entities = new()
{
    new() 
    { 
        someProp = new ClassC() { FieldValue = 4 },
        someProp2 = new ClassB() { FieldName = "Flower" } 
    },
    new() 
    { 
        someProp = new ClassA() { },
        someProp2 = new ClassC() { FieldValue = 7 } 
    }
};
```

, the resulting `values` will contain:

> 4
> Flower
> 7

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OuX03I).

Comment: amazing!!! thx!